# Improve UITableView scrolling performance while loading images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have a scrolling grid of photos that looks and functions pretty much exactly like the photo picker on the iPhone. It is constructed from a UITableView that uses a custom UITableViewCell which displays a row of photos (very similar to how [Three20](http://three20.info/) implements it).

It works great except that scrolling performance is poor. I'm already following most of the best practices for fast UITableView scrolling (à la [Tweetie](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/)).

The images are all bundled with the app. I load them on the UI thread, on demand. I use UIImage's imageNamed: so that the images will be cached after they're first loaded. Once I've scrolled through the table view once, it scrolls very smoothly.

The problem is, the first time scrolling through the table view, scrolling is jittery. I've profiled the app and found that the majority of the time is spent loading the images from the file system. They are JPEG images, already sized correctly (small). I tried using PNG images instead, but performance doesn't improve very much.

The iPhone photo picker exhibits much better loading performance. I'm wondering if combining all the photos into a single image, which I load once and then split into smaller images would be faster. It certainly works in games, but I know that's really a totally different story. Has anyone had experience doing that?

Any other ideas for how I can improve performance?

Incidentally, I'm having a similar, albeit less, performance problem for another UITableView that just uses standard UITableViewCells with one image assigned to the imageView per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try could be pre-caching all the images when the view loads.  Beyond that, perhaps loading the images in the background (even though it's loading from the filesystem and not the web).  I haven't tried this myself, but perhaps you could use something like https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and have the URLs point to the filesystem.  Users might see some placeholder images at first, but then the UI wouldn't stutter while images are loading.

Comment: I tried both techniques: pre-caching and async loading. Async loading looked terrible, since the images all load so quickly, yet slowly enough for a noticeable flicker. Pre-caching worked great. I'm worried about what happens when I need to pre-cache 350 images in a few months (I currently only need to pre-cache 100), but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: You're welcome! For the async loading, it might look better if you don't have a placeholder image, but instead just a blank area where the image will appear.  That might prevent the flickering.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using a `UITableView` to display information parsed from an RSS Feed. I ran into scrolling performance issues when there was a significant amount of data. Though I'm still working on it I suspend the parsing when the table is being scrolled. It resumes when scrolling stops. I am not at my computer, but I believe I used `tableViewDidScroll` and `tableViewDidEndDecelerating`. You can check these tableview delegates. In any case it works very well, I just need a more elegant way to pause my parsing.

Comment: Joe, if you're parsing the RSS feed in a background thread, try setting the thread priority to 0 (put this at the beginning of your background thread code: `[NSThread setThreadPriority:0]`). I found that to work really well for me, and it might solve your problem more elegantly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the PagingEnabled property to off improves the scrolling performance.

Answer (score -1):

Fantastic.  That does work like a charm!  So efficiently I ended up using insertRowAtIndexPath rather that reloading the table.  Now it behaves the way it

Thanks so much!
Joe